# net/http give 404 error when trying to call other route that isn't /

Tags: javascript, reactjs, go

I have a web app which has React as frontend and Go as backend.

My idea is to use http.handle to serve the path to React Router which then render the right component.

The problem is that when I try to connect to `localhost:8080` it goes all well, but when I try to connect to `localhost:8080/example` it give me `404 page not found`

To serve my react app I use this code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "log"
)

// frontend public path 
const public = "../frontend/public/";

func main(){
    // route handling
    http.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir(public)));
    http.Handle("/example", http.FileServer(http.Dir(public)));

    log.Println("Listening on http://locahost:8080");

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil));
}
```

My rect router:

```js
import React from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from '../pages/Home/Home';
import Admin from '../pages/Example/Example';

export default class RouteHandler extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <Router>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path='/'>
                        <Home />
                    </Route>
                    <Route exact path='/example'>
                        <Admin />
                    </Route>
                </Switch>
            </Router>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: If you use react router, you normally don't do any routing on the backend. You would resolve any request to the root path e.g. `/` ,  so that it always hits your SPA frontend. Then, form the SPA you take the URL and do what you want with it, e.g. show different "pages."

Comment: @TheFool if I understood, you would recommend to pass every route to react's router. I thought about this option, but then I thought about how I would manage API routing and there I would have a problem if I were passing all my routes to react routing. If you had any suggestion about how to manage API route I'm glad to hear it, thank you.

Comment: Oh I see, in that case maybe you could prefix your api with something like `api.myurl`.  Or you prefix all frontend routes with `/frontend`. So that you can decide on top level where to route it to. That would proably save you of defining all frontend routes on your backend as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, the problem was that with `http.Handle("/example", http.FileServer(http.Dir(public)));` golang tried to find the path `../frontend/public/example`.

To fix this problem I used `http.StripPrefix`:

```golang
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "log"
)

// frontend public path 
const public = "../frontend/public/";

func main(){
    // route handling
    http.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir(public)));
    http.Handle("/admin/", http.StripPrefix("/admin/", http.FileServer(http.Dir(public))));

    log.Println("Listening on http://locahost:8080");

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil));
}
```